# How to apply SQL 'between' keyword on TIME data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, between

--I want to use SQL - `BETWEEN` on TIME datatype.

I want to execute below query but it does not give correct result.
here, `starttime` and `endtime` both fields are typeof `smalldatetime` whichi do cast into TIME field as i need time comparision only and date's value is not actual its just dummy.

```
SELECT 
  count(1) 
FROM 
  t1 INNER JOIN t2
WHERE 
  CAST(t1.StartTime as TIME)  
  BETWEEN CAST(t2.StartTime as TIME) 
  AND CAST(t2.EndTime as TIME)
```

---

```
CAST(t1.StartTime as TIME)  is 08:00:00.0000000 
CAST(t2.StartTime as TIME)  is 07:00:00.0000000 
CAST(t2.StartTime as TIME)  is 12:00:00.0000000
```

so, above query should result record count 1 (as 8 o'clock is between 7 to 12). but it returns null.

Please suggest me what is wrong here and how to correct.

Thank You

Comment: Can you provide sample data and results so we can see the problem?

Comment: Do you mean SELECT COUNT(*)?

Comment: It's usually better to use a semi-open interval when dealing with continuous data like times, e.g. `>= start time AND < end time` rather than using `BETWEEN`. It tends to lead to more natural queries (e.g. if you run a query about the morning, and later a query about the afternoon, you tend to want events that happened at exactly midday to appear in the results of only one of those queries, rather than both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE CAST(t1.StartTime as TIME)  >= CAST(t2.StartTime as TIME) 
AND CAST(t1.StartTime as TIME) <= CAST(t2.EndTime as TIME)
```

Using this Snytax makes your queries SARGable. [Read Here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server.aspx) for more information about making your queries sargable when working with datetime/date/time datatypes.

Comment: `BETWEEN` is also sargable (your query is a `BETWEEN` without that keyword, much like a `WHILE` loop is still a `CURSOR` without the `CURSOR` keyword. Perhaps [the problem with `BETWEEN` is slightly misunderstood](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Comment: Also, in isolated cases where a `CAST` on the column is still sargable (there are not many at all), there are [other potential problems](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you for pointing this out and for the helpful link.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have stopped using BETWEEN for dates after reading your article with a heading of `What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?`

Comment: I know, I was commenting that you said "using this syntax makes your queries SARGable" but in reality this query is no more SARGable than the equivalent query using BETWEEN. The problem with BETWEEN is that most people don't understand the boundaries (and most queries do not really want both posts - e.g. BETWEEN Feb 1 and Mar 1 includes data from Mar 1 at midnight, and BETWEEN Feb 1 and Feb 28 only includes data from Feb 28 at midnight, but not from 1 AM, noon, 8 PM, etc.).

Comment: I always knew using `BETWEEN` has some caveat regarding upper and lower limits, but wasnt too sure, but after reading your article and the examples you have shown cleared the fog :)

Answer (score 0):

the syntax of between is correct. you need to specify the join and provide an `on` clause like this:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 on t1.col = t2.col
WHERE CAST(t1.StartTime as TIME)  BETWEEN CAST(t2.StartTime as TIME) AND CAST(t2.EndTime as TIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect based on your example you are looking for times in t1 between a start and end time in t2 but the two tables do not necessarily have a relationship between them on any key.

Trying to use a join in that scenario will not work easily, you'd have to move M. Ali's solution to the join predicates rather than in the where conditions.

If my assumption is correct and your simply looking for t1 rows that match your between criteria in t2 this should get you that set without the two tables having a relationship:

```
DECLARE @sampleTime AS smalldatetime = GETDATE()

CREATE TABLE #t1 (StartTime smalldatetime)
CREATE TABLE #t2 (StartTime smalldatetime, EndTime smalldatetime)

INSERT INTO #t1 (StartTime) VALUES (@sampleTime)
INSERT INTO #t1 (StartTime) VALUES (DATEADD(hh, 6, @sampleTime))

INSERT INTO #t2 (StartTime, EndTime) VALUES (DATEADD(hh, -1, @sampleTime), DATEADD(hh, 3, @sampleTime))

--  you can see only one row in t1 lands between the Start and End in t2 
SELECT  * FROM #t1
WHERE   EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #t2  WHERE CAST(#t1.StartTime AS time) BETWEEN CAST(#t2.StartTime AS time) AND CAST(#t2.EndTime AS time))


--  adding another row to t1 that now lands between the Start and End in t2 and the result
INSERT INTO #t1 (StartTime) VALUES (DATEADD(hh, 1, @sampleTime))

SELECT  * FROM #t1
WHERE   EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #t2  WHERE CAST(#t1.StartTime AS time) BETWEEN CAST(#t2.StartTime AS time) AND CAST(#t2.EndTime AS time))


DROP TABLE #t1, #t2
```